# Watson assistant capture free text as comment

Tags: chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I need to ask user to add comments in a dialog and save it to context in IBM Watson assistant.

```
Conversation:
Bot ask: Your comment?
User: You are doing good job.
Bot: Thank you for your comment.
```

Dialog Node flow:

```
Node 1: Bot ask question, then "Wait for reply".
Node 2: Try to set context: $user_comment=<"?input.text?> which is from previous node.
```

My issue: No matter what user types, bot could not recognized any intent, then the flow stop. How do I continue my flow to next node In "Bot recognize" condition?

Basically, IBM Watson Assistant tried to detect an intent upon user's comment. How do I tell Watson assistant NOT to figure out the intent to move to next node?

Your help is much appreciated.

Thank you so much

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out.

On node 2, In "Bot recognize" condition, set it to !$user_comment, then set context: user_comment=.

Thank you for your attention.

Chris